# Identify which server instance is represented by a particular java.exe on task manager

Tags: websphere-6.1, taskmanager

From my RAD workspace, I start a Websphere portal server and a Websphere App Server. Now when I go to Task Manager--> Processes, I see two java.exes running that  represent the two server instances.

How can I tell which java.exe is for the portal and which java.exe is the App Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROFILE_HOME/logs/SERVER_NAME/SERVER_NAME.pid contains the server PID.  In task manager, ensure View > Select Columns > PID (Process Identifier) is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://live.sysinternals.com/tools/procexp.exe) instead of Task Manager. It can show you the full command line and the loaded libraries for every running process; also which process started it. Usually it is easy to distinguish different Java services that way. Some services might store their PID into some file, too, but that depends on the service.